# Apache Wicket REST with Swagger UI

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, wicket-6, wicketstuff

One of my project is using Apache Wicket 6.x and I have some API (resources) using wicketstuff-rest and it is working perfectly.

But for my API documentations, I am maintaining a google document for these APIs. Problem is that whenever there are changes in any of the API, or even on new APIs... I need to update this API documentation. Chances are, this documentation may not be updated.

On my other springboot projects, I am using swagger and the API documentation can be viewed via swagger-ui.

I wonder if I can use swagger-ui with existing apache wicket 6.x project so that whenever there are new API(s) or any change on the existing API(s)... it will reflect in swagger-ui without the need to maintain any API documentation.

What I currently search is swagger2markup, but this seems to be old and I am having problems with the setup and there are very few resources on how to set this up.

Anyone who successfully setup swagger-ui with apache wicket rest?

Care to share resource/links on tutorials or how to setup swagger-ui on apache wicket rest?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an easy solution for you with Swagger but if you use Spring already then you could use [Spring REST Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html5/) to generate the documentation from the unit tests.